# Create def in ruby to convert unix timestamp to datetime in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and would like to create a simple method to convert a series of unix timestamps into datetime format. Currently, what I am doing (in console on my terminal is)

```
def foo(x) 
Time.at(:x)
end
```

Then I would pass in foo(1315922016). But I get an error

> Can't convert Symbol into an exact number

How can I revise my ruby code to allow it to accept an integer which then is put into Time.at method for conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be simple call as:

```
def foo(x) 
  Time.at(x)
end
```

Hope that helps!